# QT - Which method for showing a playerchar

Tags: qt, select, load, sprite, frame

In my PlayerSelectMenu i want to show the available characters. My idea is to have a Frame in which the character is shown. left and right of the frame are buttons to switch forward to the next character and back to the last character.
Is there a way to load the character sprite into the window?

Answer (score 0):

If you question is about "How to load an image in QML", then you can simply use the `Image` element, and set its source property to give the path of your image

```
source: "qrc:/path/to/image.png"
```

or

```
source: "file:/system/path/to/image.png"
```

---

If your question is about loading multiple frames and animate them, then there is the [`AnimatedImage` qml component](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html), that allows you to play .gif animated images for instance (possibly [animated png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) too), and the current frame. If you don't have format, then you can manually animate with a Timer and/or Animation element, manually changing the source of an `Image` element.

Answer (score 0):

I meant loading an list of playersprites into a frame in QT Creator. I'm developing a beat'm up game that has a playerselect-menu. in this menu i want to show the available characters in 2 seperate frames for player 1 and player 2.

Comment: Please post this as a comment to my answer, or in your answer, not a separate answer :)